# Left handed piano?

Tags: piano, keyboard

Is there such a thing as a piano that goes from high notes to low notes where the left hand plays the melody and right hand plays the harmony? Lol what is going on here:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bah, this video has been filmed in a mirror:
The pianist is sitting at the left side in front of a piano!

Comment: Or it was flipped digitally.

Comment: I verified this by playing in front of the mirror. I wasn't aware that mirrors do that with playing.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess would be it was shot using the selfie-cam on a smartphone.

They are often mirrored.

Answer (score 2):

There was a very rich left-handed player, who had a grand made for him (one off, no surprise there!) I mentioned it in an answer a couple of years ago. Strangely enough, not many of his musical colleagues could play it well...

Could be referenced to a question about genuine ambidextrous instruments I asked.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper and easier to play with your hands under a shroud if you want to hide your secret techniques from prying eyes?

Comment: @DavidBowling - I find that a sharp stick is quite effective...

Comment: I don't have good aim when I am playing, but perhaps a pepperspray pedal?

Comment: @DavidBowling - the practice pedal found on some pianos can be adapted to drop a blanket over the keys instead of the strings. That'd work.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easy to map an electronic keyboard to play 'backwards'.   But this is just a reversed video.

Here's a whole band of reversed marimbas.  Watch the bass player at 1'14"